# Factor "X" has new levels a,b,c... (logistic Regression)

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I'm trying to apply logistic regression on a dataset however I'm facing this problem

```
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor Margin has new levels 14 runs, 19 runs, 3 wickets, 9 wickets, 95 runs
```

I tried removing attribute Margin from test dataset however the error appeared again with a different attribute.

Here is my code

```
#applying Logistic Regression
model1 <- glm(Team1.Result ~ Matchid    +Team2  + Margin    +   Toss +  Bat + Ground +  Date +  Team1.BatRate   + Team1.Bat_SR +    Team1.BowlRate +    Team1.Bowl_SR   + Team2.BatRate +   Team2.Bat_SR +  Team2.BowlRate +    Team2.Bowl_SR, family=binomial(link='logit'),data=data_train)
summary(model1)


fitted.results <- predict(model1,newdata= test,type='response')
fitted.results <- ifelse(fitted.results > 0.5,1,0)

misClasificError <- mean(fitted.results != data_test$Survived)
print(paste('Accuracy',1-misClasificError))
```

The output of model1 is

```
(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 4.6070e+01  on 33  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 5.3617e-10  on  0  degrees of freedom
AIC: 68

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 24
```

str(data_test$Margin) and str(data_train$Margin)

```
> str(data_test$Margin)
 Factor w/ 29 levels "1 wickets","10 wickets",..: 4 25 7 29 27 16 9 22 24 19 ...
> str(data_train$Margin)
 Factor w/ 29 levels "1 wickets","10 wickets",..: 10 25 17 11 24 28 19 3 10 3 ...
```

My question is how to remove this error?

Comment: Apparently you have levels of the variables in your test set that don't exist in your training set. This is a problem in `Margin` and at least one other variable. What's your question?

Comment: Do you really want the number of wickets and runs to be treated categorically anyway?

Comment: My question is how to remove this error! and can you please elaborate what's different in my training set from my test set ?

Comment: @Gregor The data was given to me by my mentor so I'm not sure if I can change anything in it, also what difference does it make anyways? because even if I remove this column the error still occurs

Comment: I can't elaborate on the differences in your data sets because I don't have them. Perhaps if you `table(data_test$Margin)` and `table(data_train$Margin)`  you can see the differences yourself. You should be looking for levels that occur 0 times in the train data but do occur in the test set.

Comment: *"I'm not sure if I can change anything in it, also what difference does it make anyways?"*. If you can't change anything, than what do you hope to achieve? Maybe you should be asking your mentor for help? I can't give you "permission" to change things.

Comment: *"because even if I remove this column the error still occurs"* Yes, this seems to be a problem in `Margin` and at least one other variable. You didn't tell us what column in mentioned in the new error, but it should tell you the next variable with the problem. (You did take `Margin` out of the model too, not just the data, right? You can't give a model partial information...)

Comment: he is on leave so I can't :/ + I was just asking if it makes any big difference since I'm pretty new in R sorry if I appeared rude :/

Comment: I checked and it's appearing in 3 variables , Margin+Ground+ Date. I will try the above table solution you posted

Comment: Just to be clear, the `table` is a diagnosis method, not a solution. You can't ask a model to predict for classes of data it hasn't seen. The easiest thing to do would be to lump those into an "unknown" category. (Or treat them as numeric, since the underlying data seems to be numeric, not categorical.) I just want to emphasize that the error is indicating a problem *with your data* more than with the model.

Comment: Ok thanks George I will try converting them in numeric attributes!